# _curses.error: prefresh() returned ERR

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
for j in range(10):
    for i in range(0, 20000, conf.batch_size):
        x1 = Xtrain[0][i:i + conf.batch_size]
        x2 = Xtrain[1][i:i + conf.batch_size]
        y = ytrain[i:i + conf.batch_size]
        _, summaries, accc, loss = sess.run([train_step, train_summary_op, acc, cost],
                feed_dict={input_1: x1, input_2: x2, input_3: y, dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
        time_str = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        print("{}: loss {:g}, acc {:g}".format(time_str, loss, accc))
        train_summary_writer.add_summary(summaries)
    print("\nEvaluation:")
    accc = sess.run(acc, feed_dict={input_1: Xtest[0], input_2: Xtest[1], input_3: ytest, dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("test accuracy:", accc)
```

**Error：**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/python_workspace/intel/MPCNN/train.py", line 124, in 
>       feed_dict={input_1: x1, input_2: x2, input_3: y, dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\wrappers\framework.py", line 411, in run
>       self._run_call_count))
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\wrappers\local_cli_wrapper.py", line 212, in
>   on_run_start
>       self._run_start_response = self._launch_cli()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\wrappers\local_cli_wrapper.py", line 366, in
>   _launch_cli
>       title_color=self._title_color)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\cli\curses_ui.py", line 460, in run_ui
>       self._dispatch_command(init_command)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\cli\curses_ui.py", line 699, in _dispatch_com
>   mand
>       self._display_output(screen_output)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\cli\curses_ui.py", line 1044, in _display_out
>   put
>       self._scroll_output(_SCROLL_HOME)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\cli\curses_ui.py", line 1282, in _scroll_outp
>   ut
>       self._screen_render_nav_bar()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\debug\cli\curses_ui.py", line 1295, in _screen_rend
>   er_nav_bar
>       self._max_x)
>   _curses.error: prefresh() returned ERR

I don't know how to deal with it,please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the same thing, but for me the error was because Curses was trying to output beyond the range of the terminal window. By expanding my window, I no longer had the error. Now for the other errors....

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provide, the expression:

```
feed_dict={input_1: Xtest[0], input_2: Xtest[1], input_3: ytest, dropout_keep_prob: 1.0})
```

generates an error somewhere inside Anaconda3.

Find out what anaconda3 expects. Then check what it is that you are giving anaconda3. If everything is as could be expected, then try googling for the error (`"_curses.error: prefresh() returned ERR"`). Chanses are you are not the first person who has encountered this problem.